# Understanding the dot notation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I import a module, such as sys, I am assuming that I am importing a script, and in order to access its functions, I have to use the dot notation.
For example, I want to write something out to the console:

```
    sys.stderr.write("Error")
```

Here, I access the stderr "function?" from the module sys, but then I access its write attribute which is also a function? How do I know if stderr is a class that is subclassing sys, or if it is a function?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you open the Python interpreter, `import sys` and type `sys.stderr` it outputs `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='cp437'>`, telling you that `sts.stderr` is a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object.  Doing that same for `sys.stderr.write` gives you `<built-in method write of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x00B18830>` (This is for Python 3.5.0)

Comment: `"How do I know if stderr is a class that is subclassing sys"` It sounds like you are not using the term "subclassing" correctly. "Subclassing" means that a class inherits from another class, not that it is in a module's namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you import a module (like `sys` or anything), the dot-notation may then refer to *anything it contains*. You could also import a 'package' contains modules, classes, methods in classes, functions in modules, etc.

```
>>> import sys
>>> type(sys)
<class 'module'>
>>> sys.stderr
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='cp437'>
>>> type(sys.stderr)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> type(sys.stderr.write)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>>
```

It's meant to be generic sort-of-attribute access where each thing inside another is accessed via the dot, as if it was an attribute of that object, which it is.

I believe it's meant to be ambiguous so that the user of a module/package does not need to be concerned with the implementation details of those objects. And if they change, as long as the *structure* and names are maintained, the actual object it refers to is not of concern to the user. They could always use `type()` or `help()` to look at the details or use other introspection tools.

Answer (score 0):

The dot is a generic **element** reference, not merely a function.  This says to get the `stderr` element of `sys`, then get the `write` element of `stderr`.  For this to work, `stderr` must be an object that contains elements, and `write` must be a callable element ... since the parentheses mean that we're trying to call `write`.

We do have to know the general semantic of each element: which are packages, which are constants, which are functions, etc.

Comment: note that "write" can be any callable, not necessarily a function